# XSL - using variables in nodepath

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat, xslt

I have a xsl as below

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="concat('some','stuff')" />

<xsl:if test="$foo">
  <xsl:element name="hello">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="-1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:element name="region">
            <xsl:value-of select="$foo/child"/>  <!-- foo is variable, but always has a 'child' node -->
        </xsl:element>

  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

I get the below output:

```
<hello id="-1">
```

and an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xpath.objects.XString incompatible with
>   org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the exception is coming from your XSL.  Show the entire stack trace as well as your Java code, and clearly mark the line in the Java where the exception is thrown.  These are fundamental requirements for asking questions about exceptions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am able to get the <hello> node in the output, it fails at the exact line `<xsl:value-of select="$foo/child"/>`

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example, which is: input XML and XSL. What Java says: `$foo` seems to be a string, not a node. But you can only select children from nodes, not from strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="concat('some','stuff')" />
```

will create a string with value 'somestuff'.

The string turns your line

```
<xsl:value-of select="$foo/child"/>
```

effectively into

```
<xsl:value-of select="'somestuff'/child"/>
```

which is not a valid XPath expression.

Thie string cannot be used in any node expressions, only in string operations.
Replace your

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="concat('some','stuff')" />
```

by something like

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="./somestuff" />
```

which returns a node.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Still a little confused though. Is there a way I can use `./` with `concat'?

Comment: No. `concat` will always create a string. If you really want to do that sort of thing, you'd need something like `select="//*[local-name()=concat('some','stuff')]"/>`, but I'd recommend finding an easier approach.